# How does Devise hide some fields when output json

Tags: devise, mongoid, ruby-grape

I am using Grape + Mongoid + Devise.
I found that the Devise user model have more fields (e.g. encrypted_password, sign_in_count, last_sign_in_at) than the user json output when I wrote API response.
I have searched in Devise code, didn't find anything like custom to_json, how does Devise achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on Grape, but on Rails you can do it with a **serializer** (as Grape has many code compatible with Rails, I think there's a big chance to work).

To use a serializer, you need to include the "active_model_serializers" gem.

Example:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :email, :username
end
```

On this example, Devise will always print only these 3 fields on a JSON output.

To include all attributes except some of them, you can do something like this:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes(*(User.attribute_names - ["date_created", "first_name"] ).map(&:to_sym))
end
```

Also, at least on Rails, you'll want to remove the root from the output. To do this, add this code to your application_controller.rb:

```
def default_serializer_options  
  {root: false}  
end
```